# Unable to display a column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to display the column EQ_NM in Table2 from Records. In Table1, EQ_NM is displayed as I execute it while in Table2 it is not displayed and produced an error. How can I display per EQ_NM?

Table1 as follows:

```
SELECT EQ_ID, EQ_NM, 'Interrupt' GUBUN, INTR_CNT CNT
FROM
(
SELECT CASE WHEN INTR_CNT=0 THEN '-' ELSE EQ_ID END AS EQ_ID, CASE WHEN INTR_CNT=0 THEN '-'
                ELSE SUBSTR(EQ_NM,1,4)END AS EQ_NM, INTR_CNT
FROM(
SELECT EQ_ID,COMMENT EQ_NM, SUM(INTR_CNT) INTR_CNT
FROM RECORDS
WHERE ST_CODE= 'A503CC'
AND GD_CODE= 'M6321'
AND MNG_YN= 'Y'
AND STEP_ID='APT'
AND YMD= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD'
GROUP BY EQ_ID, COMMENT
)
ORDER BY INTR_CNT DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <=10
```

Table2:

```
SELECT ST_CODE,GD_CODE,STP_NAME,YMD,UNIT_CODE,BI, BA,EQ_NM, INTR_CNT
FROM(
SELECT CASE WHEN INTR_CNT=0 THEN '-' ELSE EQ_ID END AS EQ_ID, CASE WHEN INTR_CNT=0 THEN '-'
                ELSE SUBSTR(EQ_NM,1,4)END AS EQ_NM, INTR_CNT, 
                ST_CODE,GD_CODE,STP_NAME,YMD,UNIT_CODE,BI, BA
FROM(
SELECT
A.ST_CODE,
A.GD_CODE,
A.EQ_NM,
A.STEP_ID AS STP_NAME,
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'JAN'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'FEB'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'MAR'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'APR'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'MAY'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'JUN'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'JUL'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'AUG'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'SEP'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'OCT'
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.YMD,5,2))) = '1' THEN 'NOV'
ELSE 'DEC' END AS YMD
,'M' AS UNIT_CODE, SUBSTR(A.YMD,1,6) AS RN
,CASE WHEN (SUM(NVL(A.INTR_CNT, 0)) + SUM(NVL(A.BRDN_CNT,0)))=0
THEN ROUND(SUM(NVL(A.OPER,0)),1)
ELSE ROUND(SUM(NVL(A.OPER,0)) / (SUM(A.INTR_CNT,0)) + SUM(NVL(A.BRDN_CNT)))/60,1)
END AS BI
,CASE WHEN (SUM(NVL(A.INTR_CNT, 0)) + SUM(NVL(A.BRDN_CNT,0)) + 
SUM(NVL(A.WRK_PRE_CNT,0))+SUM(NVL(A.PROD_CHNGE_CNT,0)) +SUM(NVL(A.QUAL_CNT,0)) +
SUM(NVL(A.EXATN_CNT,0)) + SUM(NVL(A.STE_LOSS_CNT,0)) + SUM(NVL(A.IDLE_CNT,0)))=0
THEN 0
ELSE ROUND (SUM(NVL(A.OPER,0)), / SUM(NVL(A.INTR_CNT,0)) + SUM(NVL(A.BRDN_CNT,0)) + 
SUM(NVL(A.WRK_PRE_CNT,0)) + SUM(NVL(A.PROD_CHNGE_CNT,0)) + SUM(NVL(A.QUAL_CNT,0)) +
SUM(NVL(MTR_CNT,0)) + SUM(NVL(A.STE_LOSS_CNT,0)) + SUM(NVL(A.IDLE_CNT,0))) /60,1)
END AS BA
FROM RECORDS A
WHERE 1=1
AND A.ST_CODE= 'A503CC'
AND A.GD_CODE= 'M6321'
AND A.YMD BETWEEN TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE-1,-1),'YYYYMM')AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'YYYYMM)
AND A.STEP_ID='TP'
AND A.MNG_YN = 'Y'
GROUP BY A.ST_CODE, A.GD_CODE,A.EQ_NM, A.STEP_ID, SUBSTR(A.YMD,1,6), TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR9A.YMD,5,2)))
) A ORDER BY A.RN
```

Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: Check Table2 code. A single quote is missing in the line AND A.YMD BETWEEN TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE-1,-1),'YYYYMM')AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'YYYYMM)

Comment: thank you for that. As I put the missing single quote there is still have an error "ORA-00904: "A"."EQP_NAME": invalid identifier "